# Invalid login when trying to enter Airflow on the Web

Tags: authentication, terminal, airflow

I've created an Admin user, checked if it in the db, tried different passwords and usernames, but same error occurs...

I set in config file

```
rbac = True
authenticate = True
auth_backends = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

It seems that I tried everything imaginable pls someone help me...